# Как разделить цитату на две?

Tags: поддержка, markdown

Хочется разделить цитату на две части без использования между ними явного печатного символа или горизонтальной линии `<hr>`, т.е. чтобы просто было несколько пикселей белого фона. Возможно ли это?

Примерно вот так:

[image: разделенные цитаты]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно вставить комментарий:

```
>Первая цитата

<!-- -->

>Вторая цитата
```

> Первая цитата

> Вторая цитата

Comment: Для примеров кода тоже работает, что иногда оч. удобно

Comment: Шикардос. Вроде как достаточно просто `<!`

Comment: @alexolut, лучше все-таки корректные теги писать :)

Comment: @Grundy работает - значит сойдет :) надо кнопки на экранной клавиатуре экономить

Comment: Особенно пригождается, когда куски кода на разных языках. (Иначе автораскраска не справляется.)

Comment: @VladD, для раскраски лучше хинты специальные использовать, а не просто пустой комментарий

Comment: @Grundy: Ну, обычно если разделить куски на разных языках, то автораскраска справляется. Если нет, тогда пригодятся хинты, да.